# Removing closed button from dialog window Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to delete the "close" button that appears when the puzzle is completed. I can do this, but if the user trys, they can click on the location of the hidden button and it will pretty much crash the page and scatter the puzzle everywhere. Anyone know how I can solve this? The hidden button is in the top-left of the puzzle, clicking around there will show what I mean.

I am deleting the button in the CSS code by doing:

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
 visibility: hidden;
}
```

Here is my JSFiddle, looks kinda strange on fiddle but oh well, still crashes it.

http://jsfiddle.net/QY5jb/3/

Comment: Don't know what you are talking about, nothing crashed when I clicked around where the button was supposed to be. When it was `hidden`, it just doesn't appear (obviously) but ask didn't react to clicking int its vicinity.

Comment: If you finish the puzzle and then just click right above the first puzzle piece (top left) the puzzle will go crazy. It's not a real big deal because doubt that users will do that but still would like to fix it. If you can't recreate it, not sure what to say.

Comment: I did get your problem to work. When I deleted the `.ui-dialog-titlebar-close` node from the page, the problem still happened, which leads me to believe that the error doesn't lay in the close button.

Comment: Hmmm yes your right, I thought I tried that. Ok back to the drawing board. Seems to only happen when the puzzle is completed though

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it with something else. Pure css will not remove the element. If you want to remove it, I'd write myself a function that will hide the element. For example

```
function delete_element(e){
  e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
}
```

and call this function when your puzzle is completed. Where e is your .ui-dialog-titlebar-close

so for example

```
var element = document.querySelector('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close');
delete_element(element);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did this though and still seems like I can click on the hidden button. Did you try this and it solved it?